# Dependence of Rabi oscillations on laser power

Tags: quantum-optics, cavity-qed, laser-cavity, optics

Is there an expression for the dependence of the Rabi oscillations of a system on the laser power? The system I'm considering is an electron spin in a quantum dot.

Comment: If the frequency of light is in resonance with spin splitting energy, then rabi frequency is $\Omega = \frac{\mu.E}{\hbar}$. This can be shown easily, by solving TDSE in interaction picture.

Comment: Is it the laser field that is driving spin?  When I look at Rabi oscillations in atomic systems (Rb optical pumping) it is some RF B-field that drive them.

Comment: There is also an external magnetic field on the electron spin.